# Get Mercurial to tell you the hgrc files it loads

Tags: mercurial, hgrc

I often have trouble finding the hgrc files loaded by Mercurial.

I know the possible locations are documented at http://linux.die.net/man/5/hgrc, but there are quite a few of them, and they vary from platform to platform, and they depend on things like the "Mercurial installation directory" which is yet another thing to have to track down. And sometimes, it seems like it's loading hgrc files from locations that are not on that list at all!

It would be great if I could get Mercurial to *tell* me which hgrc files it's loading, so I don't have to spend time searching for them. Basically, I'd like to be able to pass `hg` an option, like `hg -debug-hgrc-paths` and have it print the full path to each `hgrc` file that it loads. Much like how you can get `gcc` to print the header file search paths it is using with `gcc -v -E`. Does anyone know of such an option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be more than you actually need but

```
hg --debug showconfig
```

will tell you quite a bit about what values are being set from where.

Comment: Excellent! The first few lines of that output tell me exactly what I need.